# How to found in Rails using a method that is not an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do you make the following work...

```
Beagle.beagles.where(:snount => "short")
```

...in situations where a `snout` method id defined for `Beagle`, but there is no `snout` column in the `beagles` table?

Comment: Or maybe you can try thinking-sphinx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a scope (i.e. an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object) then I think you're out of luck, because `where` deals with DB query logic, not model instance methods. But if you just need to get an array of results that satisfy the method requirement, then this will work:

```
Beagle.select { |b| b.snout == "short" }
```

Note that this will grab all records from the DB, *then* select the ones you want from them. Here's the generated SQL:

```
Beagle Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "beagles".* FROM "beagles"
```

See also: [instance method in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198660/instance-method-in-scope)

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this

```
beagles = Beagle.find(:all)
beagles.each do |beagle|
if beagle.snount == "short"
beagles_selected << beagle
end
end
```

you will then have a `beagles_selected` array containing all the beagles you need

Comment: Thanks. Thought I might end up writing a quick method like this but first wanted to check if the vocab existed already.

Comment: there is a shorthand method for this in ruby, called `select`, see shioyama's answer